# How to prove uncorrelation for this case?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

So if I have random variables $X$ and $Y$ that assume values $-1$, $0$, and $1$, where

$P_X(-1) = P_X(1) = P_Y(-1) = P_Y(1) = \frac{2}{5} $ and $P_X(0) = P_Y(0) = \frac{1}{5} $

how to show that they are uncorrelated?

I have tried to do something like here: [independence and uncorrelation proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342493/independence-and-uncorrelation-proof), but did not work.

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't given enough information to tell whether they're uncorrelated. What you've given is only the probability distributions of both of them. But what is the JOINT distribution of the two?

Comment: That is all the information that the exercise gives me.

Answer (score 0):

This proof is actually showing that independence of r.v. implies zero correlation. Another approach is not possible, just like @MichaelHardy noted in comments section.

Two random variables are uncorrelated if $$E(XY)=E(X)E(Y).$$
It can be easily seen that $$E(X)=E(Y)=0.$$ 
So we need to find $XY$ distribution. And we get:
$$P(XY=-1)=\frac{8}{25} $$ 
$$P(XY=0)=\frac{9}{25} $$
$$P(XY=1)=\frac{8}{25} $$
Which also has zero mean. Hence r.v. $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: Would it help if I said that this question is in a book about Fuzzy Theory? Cause later he even asks to show that these two variables are not independents.

Comment: To show that the variables are not independent, you would have to specify the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

> So if I have random variables $X$ and $Y$ that assume values $-1$, $0$, and $1$, where
>
> $P_X(-1) = P_X(1) = P_Y(-1) = P_Y(1) = \frac{2}{5} $ and $P_X(0) = P_Y(0) = \frac{1}{5} $
>
> how to show that they are uncorrelated?

You cannot if this is all the information which you have available.

For example, it is *possible* that $Y=X$, and then they would definitely be correlated.